# Replacing Column Value with Randomised Values

Tags: r, dataframe

Hi guys I am trying to replace a certain value in **a dataframe** with randomised numerical values within a certain range.

Sample dataframe is provided below and I want to replace all numerical 3 with values between 0 and 0.1.

```
df <- data.frame(datay = sample(1:5, 10, replace = TRUE), 
                 dataz = sample(1:10, 10, replace = TRUE))
```

**Input:**

```
   datay dataz
1      5     8
2      5     3
3      2     1
4      5    10
5      4     5
6      1     6
7      1     8
8      3     2
9      3     9
10     3     4
```

**Output:**

```
    datay dataz
1      5     8
2      5     0.05
3      2     1
4      5    10
5      4     5
6      1     6
7      1     8
8      0.05     2
9      0.02     9
10     0.01     4
```

Comment: I still find the two columns that you initially had

Comment: Sorry, amended!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can also use `runif` to generate a random numbers between two values.

```
inds <- df$datay == 3
df$datay[inds] <- runif(sum(inds), 0, 0.001)

df
#      datay dataz
#1  0.000555     k
#2  5.000000     v
#3  4.000000     n
#4  2.000000     q
#5  1.000000     l
#6  2.000000     n
#7  0.000121     u
#8  0.000794     z
#9  1.000000     x
#10 2.000000     d
```

**EDIT**

For doing this for all the columns, we can do

```
mat <- which(df == 3, arr.ind = TRUE)
#If you need only for selected columns say for first two columns do
#mat <- which(df[1:2] == 3, arr.ind = TRUE)
df[mat] <- runif(nrow(mat), 0, 0.001)

df
#      datay    dataz
#1  5.000000  8.00000
#2  5.000000  0.00078
#3  2.000000  1.00000
#4  5.000000 10.00000
#5  4.000000  5.00000
#6  1.000000  6.00000
#7  1.000000  8.00000
#8  0.000144  2.00000
#9  0.000965  9.00000
#10 0.000771  4.00000
```

Comment: hey ronak, regarding your solution, could you amend the code to include more columns?

Comment: @MatthewLoh updated the code to include all columns.

Answer (score 0):

We can create a logical index based on the occurrence of value 3 in 'datay' and replace with the `sample` from the specified `seq`

```
i1 <- df$datay == 3
df$datay[i1] <- sample(seq(0, 0.01, by = 0.001), sum(i1), replace = TRUE)
df
#   datay dataz
#1  1.000     o
#2  1.000     y
#3  1.000     y
#4  0.005     b
#5  1.000     b
#6  5.000     n
#7  4.000     q
#8  4.000     c
#9  2.000     a
#10 0.001     k
```

---

If we need to use it on multiple columns (the column names are made up)

```
nm1 <- c("col1", "col2", "col3")
df[nm1] <- lapply(df[nm1], function(x) replace(x, i1, sample(seq(0, 0.01, 
             by = 0.001), sum(i1), replace = TRUE)))
```

---

Or with `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
      mutate_at(vars(nm1), ~ replace(., i1, sample(seq(0, 0.01, 
             by = 0.001), sum(i1), replace = TRUE)))
```

Or if it is to be applied across only numeric columns

```
df %>%
    mutate_if(is.numeric, ~ replace(., datay == 3, sample(seq(0, 0.01, 
             by = 0.001), sum(i1), replace = TRUE)))
```

---

If we don't want to change the original object, use `replace`

```
transform(df, datay = replace(datay, i1, sample(seq(0, 0.01, 
             by = 0.001), sum(i1), replace = TRUE)))
```

---

Another option is `runif`

```
transform(df, datay = replace(datay, i1, runif(sum(i1), 0, 0.001)))
```

---

or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[datay == 3, datay := sample(seq(0, 0.01, by = 0.001), .N, replace = TRUE)]
```

Comment: hi akrun, thanks so much! How do i expand this across the entire dataframe? Does it work across mutiple columns?

Comment: @MatthewLoh. Updated the answer

Comment: For the amended code, i still need to assign a value to i1?

Comment: @MatthewLoh. I asked earlier regarding the condition and you didn't answer that `i1 <- df$datay == 3`

Comment: @MatthewLoh. Your question is not clear.  It is better to post initially with the question you want to solve.  Now, I have made all these efforts and you have a different question

Comment: so sorry about that akrun! i will amend the inital post to better reflect what i require!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196239/discussion-between-matthew-loh-and-akrun).